# Android listview actionlistener

Tags: android, android-listview, actionlistener

I have one `ListView` and in this `ListView` I have array of strings. I want set `ActionListener` to this `ListView`, but I don't know, maybe finding by index. I must go to the next new `Activity`, when the user clicks on one of these `ListItems`.

This is what I have already:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview2); 
final ReadSubjectSelectionListAdapter adapter = new ReadSubjectSelectionListAdapter(getActivity(), subject);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And:

```
public void loadSubjects(){
  subject = new String[11]; 
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){ 
      subject[i] = new String();
    }

  subject[0]=("Math"); 
  subject[1]=("Kaz history"); 
  subject[2]=("Kaz language"); 
  subject[3]=("Rus language"); 
  subject[4]=("Eng language");
  subject[5]=("Physics"); 
  subject[6]=("Chemistry"); 
  subject[7]=("Biology"); 
  subject[8]=("Geography"); 
  subject[9]=("World history"); 
  subject[10]=("Kaz literature");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `setOnItemClickListener`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)

Comment: if you post some code of what you have tried already, its much more easy for people to help

Comment: @user2579806 Please don't post your code in comments, but rather edit your question to include all additional data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like this:

```
myListview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int pos, long id) 
  {
    Intentintent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position",pos);    
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myListview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int pos, long id) 
  {
    Intentintent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position",pos);    
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

Add permission in manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".NewActivity" />
```

Comment: nice copy-paste of my answer Oo